# eslint arrow-body-style issue

Tags: javascript, eslint

I configured my eslint so it uses the arrow-body-style as needed:

`arrow-body-style: ["error", "as-needed"]`

But I'm getting an error below for some reason.

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  Product.find({})
    .select('name price _id')
    .then(items => {
      const response = {
        count: items.length,
        products: items.map(item => { // eslint points the error here
          return {
            name: item.name,
            price: item.price,
            _id: item._id,
            request: {
              type: 'GET',
              url: `http://localhost:3000/products/${item._id}`
            }
          };
        })
      };
      res.status(200).json(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
    });
});
```

How exactly am I supposed to re-write my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to omit `return` keyword and wrap the result into parenthesis:

```
products: items.map(item => ({
  name: item.name,
  price: item.price,
  _id: item._id,
  request: {
    type: 'GET',
    url: `http://localhost:3000/products/${item._id}`
  }
}))
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `arrow-body-style: ["error", "as-needed"]` configuration is redundant as it is the default behaviour. You don't need setting it again as it is already set as the default form.

> **as-needed**

*Examples of incorrect code for this rule with the default "as-needed" option:*

```
/*eslint arrow-body-style: ["error", "as-needed"]*/
/*eslint-env es6*/

let foo = () => {
    return 0;
};
let foo = () => {
    return {
       bar: {
            foo: 1,
            bar: 2,
        }
    };
};
```

*Examples of correct code for this rule with the default "as-needed" option:*

```
/*eslint arrow-body-style: ["error", "as-needed"]*/
/*eslint-env es6*/

let foo = () => 0;
let foo = (retv, name) => {
    retv[name] = true;
    return retv;
};
let foo = () => ({
    bar: {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
    }
});
let foo = () => { bar(); };
let foo = () => {};
let foo = () => { /* do nothing */ };
let foo = () => {
    // do nothing.
};
let foo = () => ({ bar: 0 });
```

[ESLint Docs on arrow-body](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style)

In your code sample it should be this way:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  Product.find({})
    .select('name price _id')
    .then(items => {
      const response = {
        count: items.length,
        products: items.map(item => ({ // no more errors
             name: item.name,
             price: item.price,
             _id: item._id,
             request: {
               type: 'GET',
               url: `http://localhost:3000/products/${item._id}`
            });
        })
      };
      res.status(200).json(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
    });
});
```

Since you're simply returning a plain object, there's no need for the extra pair of braces and `return`. Wrapping the object in parentheses `({ ... })`, works as that is implicitly returned.